# Accessing segments on Three.js Cylinder

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

so I'm playing around with Cylinder Geometry from Three.js https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/CylinderGeometry

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/lklancir/pen/pdaPoY

```
        var gui = new dat.GUI();
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 50 );
        camera.position.z = 30;

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 1 );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        var orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        orbit.enableZoom = false;

        var lights = [];
        lights[ 0 ] = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0 );
        lights[ 1 ] = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0 );
        lights[ 2 ] = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0 );

        lights[ 0 ].position.set( 0, 200, 0 );
        lights[ 1 ].position.set( 100, 200, 100 );
        lights[ 2 ].position.set( - 100, - 200, - 100 );

        scene.add( lights[ 0 ] );
        scene.add( lights[ 1 ] );
        scene.add( lights[ 2 ] );

        var mesh = new THREE.Object3D();

        mesh.add( new THREE.LineSegments(

            new THREE.Geometry(),

            new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {
                color: 0xffffff,
                transparent: true,
                opacity: 0.5
            } )

        ) );

        mesh.add( new THREE.Mesh(

            new THREE.Geometry(),

            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                color: 0x156289,
                emissive: 0x072534,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                flatShading: true
            } )

        ) );


 function renderMeshCylinder( mesh ) {

    var data = {
        radiusTop : 5,
        radiusBottom : 5,
        height : 30,
        radiusSegments : 60,
        heightSegments : 60,
        openEnded : true,
        thetaStart : 0,
        thetaLength : twoPi
    };





    function generateGeometry() {

        updateGroupGeometry( mesh,
            new THREE.CylinderGeometry(
                data.radiusTop,
                data.radiusBottom,
                data.height,
                data.radiusSegments,
                data.heightSegments,
                data.openEnded,
                data.thetaStart,
                data.thetaLength
            )
        );

    }

    var folder = gui.addFolder( 'THREE.CylinderGeometry' );

    folder.add( data, 'radiusTop', 1, 30 ).onChange( generateGeometry );
    folder.add( data, 'radiusBottom', 1, 30 ).onChange( generateGeometry );
    folder.add( data, 'height', 1, 50 ).onChange( generateGeometry );
    folder.add( data, 'radiusSegments', 3, 64 ).step( 1 ).onChange( generateGeometry );
    folder.add( data, 'heightSegments', 1, 64 ).step( 1 ).onChange( generateGeometry );
    folder.add( data, 'openEnded' ).onChange( generateGeometry );
    folder.add( data, 'thetaStart', 0, twoPi ).onChange( generateGeometry );
    folder.add( data, 'thetaLength', 0, twoPi ).onChange( generateGeometry );


    generateGeometry();

}

renderMeshCylinder(mesh);
        var options = {};

        scene.add( mesh );

        var prevFog = false;

        var render = function () {

            requestAnimationFrame( render );

            if ( ! options.fixed ) {

                mesh.rotation.x += 0;
                mesh.rotation.y += 0;

            }

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        };

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', function () {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }, false );

        render();
```

I'm trying to figure out (but in vain) how can I reach a specific segment by it's index or coordinate and color it in a different color (https://screencast.com/t/GIeZq3XSKCOy)

Would anyone be able to provide some guidance here or how to approach this issue further?

Comment: DId you try to use [`THREE.Raycaster()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Raycaster)?

Comment: Not working for me, however, I'm using now a different approach. I'm trying to add two cylinders and use the second one for manipulating eg. "welds" on the pipe, but also can't manage to implement this idea haha, fuk me I'm a noob for 3js

Comment: _Not working for me_ explains nothing. How did you use it? If you really did.

Comment: Well, I have tried, but probably there is much more to implementing raycaster which I can't figure out as I tried to call it and I can't manage to get any shading and that's not working for me, unfortunately. I did hoever manage to get it working with the second solution and it eases my mind but do not know if accesing any particular segement in the proposed problem is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an example of how you do it, using `THREE.Raycaster()` and `THREE.CylinderGeometry()`.

[image]

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(5, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x818181);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(2, 2, 15, 32, 20, true), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
  wireframe: false,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide
}));
mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI * .5;
scene.add(mesh);

var wire = new THREE.LineSegments(new THREE.WireframeGeometry(mesh.geometry), new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: "black"
}));
mesh.add(wire);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersects;
document.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown, false);

function onMouseDown(event) {

  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(mesh);

  if (intersects.length == 0) return;

  intersects[0].face.color.setHex(0xff0000);
  intersects[0].object.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
}

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you mate. As I said, I'm quite a noob in this and need some time to figure this things out. Have made one solution but this is also the one I tried initially. Thanks for your time. If you could share your pen, I would be much grateful :)

Comment: @klanc You're welcome ) You can use the code from the snippet. Also, there's a copy of it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/ohe5c2ce/).

Comment: Thank you very much broski! :)